# Force http to one filder rest force https

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to force non-https to only one folder on the site but the rest all should be https. Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^reports$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)$ /page.php?title=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you have is, that even the reports-folder gets forced to https. Is that right?

That would be, because you put that rule first. The general rule order should be: Most specific first, most general last. So your general https enforcing rule should be last. Or at least it must be after your http enforce rule.

Also you only force /reports/ to http. Everything in that directory would be https again. I think you should change it to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/reports/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I see it correctly, you enforce everything to not start with www. Put that rule after the reports-http rule and change it to https. This will save you one redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Than your https-enforce rule and than the rewrite to page.php if not existing file or directory.

Comment: All is ok but when i open reports its redirecting to non-https that is ok but its not opening the page its saying: The page isn’t redirecting properly

Comment: Please check in firebug or chrome developer tools (or whatever you are using) which redirecty are happening. Maybe there is another redirect run after the http enforce.

Comment: I have firebug but how to check errors about the redirect using firbug ? I am not sure how. sorry

Comment: Open Firebug and go into the NETWORK view, then load your page. You should see redirects at the top of the list (if they happen) with status code 301 or 302.